# Authenticate a user using Laravel functions for an Android application

Tags: php, android, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I am wanting to create an Android / iPhone application to enable mobile phone users to have the same functionality as the website.

The website's authentication works as planned:

```php
Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))
```

What I have is another `auth.php` within the `public/app/` folder (I will add the .htaccess later!) that will authenticate users logging in through their mobile phones. Ideally, to make it simpler, I'm wanting to use all of the Laravel controller functions that my web app uses.

I know the `Auth::` function resides in the `BaseController` but I'm unsure of how to access this within the /public folder, or if this is it the suggested method.

As anyone else authenticated a user through their mobile phone through Laravel?

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a route in the `app/routes.php` for authenticate a mobile user.

```
Route::post('mobile/auth', function() {
    // your stuff
});
```

or via controller:

```
// app/routes.php
// connect the route to a controller
Route::post('mobile/auth', 'MobileAuthController@auth');

class MobileAuthController extends BaseController
{
    public function auth()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Is this what you mean? or else i misunderstand you.

You're [authentication is pretty basic,](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security) checkout the [damn good documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing) on the laravel website for better examples.